# translate plotmath latex

Tags: r, plotmath, knitr

I started using the awesome `knitr` package, and whilst I love the idea of using `tikz` graphics, it's not always very practical (time consuming). Thus, I end up switching back and forth between the good old `pdf` device, and `tikz`. Mathematical expressions are generally not handled in the same way in both devices; I find it much preferable to use LaTeX syntax in `tikz`, but it becomes hard to read in `pdf`, and vice-versa.

Have there been attempts at providing a framework to seamlessly switch from one notation to another? Something like a `translate(x, from="plotmath", to="tex", ams=TRUE, ...)` function, that could be hooked internally with `knitr` to the device in use. How would one go about doing it?

Comment: would this question get better responses at tex.stackexchange.com?

Comment: they'd probably wonder what on Earth `plotmath` means, ¿no?

Comment: Have you tried function `expr2latex` from package [`simsalapar`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/simsalapar/index.html)?

Comment: 4 years later I no longer need it. Feel free to post as an answer though. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

This sounds hard to me. Translation from `plotmath` to LaTeX may be easier, e.g. replace `alpha` with `\alpha`, and `x[i]` with `x_{i}`, etc, but the other way can be difficult since `plotmath` is only a "subset" of LaTeX expressions.

If the time-consuming generation of tikz graphics is an issue for you, you may consider turning on the cache (as I did in the `knitr` manual and many other example documents). Once a tikz figure is generated, it will not be regenerated the next time if `cache=TRUE`, so it will be pretty fast, and it will be even faster if you also convert tikz to pdf by the chunk option `external=TRUE`.

The only reason that I may not use tikz is when the plot is too large in size, as I explained in the manual. Other than that, tikz is always preferable to me. This is slightly off-topic, though.

Comment: I've used `cache`, and it does help to some extent, but the combination `ggplot2` + `tikz` remains quite slow, for the first run at least. By time-consuming, I also mean the fact that `tikz` is necessarily a non-interactive device. In contrast, I can easily switch between, say, `quartz()` and `pdf()` using the same labels and annotations.

Comment: plotmath to latex is probably the most useful conversion, but even that is not so trivial when dealing with obscure `bquote`, `substitute`, etc. constructs.

Comment: Yes, only the first run is slow.